# Why doesn't the function Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅ include the 'savings' variable?

Tags: macroeconomics

Why isn't the function Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅, actually: Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)-S+I(r)+G̅, or Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+G̅ ?

What is my reasoning behind this:

The consumption function includes all the money you are legally allowed to spend (ie: after paying taxes). But, as we know, a part of this money can be saved.

We know that:

- The consumption function is the amount of money one can choose to either consume or save. So, why not removing the Savings option?
- The function Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅ can be altered to: Supply of Y= Demand of Y. And I don't think that savings are part of the Demand of Y. That is why, we would have to deduct it from the equation?

So, do we write: Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅, instead of Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)-S+I(r)+G̅, because S<I(r)? How could we even compare savings to the interest "RATES"?

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I could not parse what you mean by '*How could we even compare savings to the interest "RATES"?*'

Answer (score 1):

Savings are included in $I$, e.g.: storing money in the bank which is lent out to people making physical investments. Keeping cans of food at home or similar things that may be considered saving from a laymen's perspective is not considered savings from a macro point of view, and are counted in $C$. (Thanks to [1muflon1 for the correction](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/52647/why-doesnt-the-function-y%cc%85-cy%cc%85-t%cc%85irg%cc%85-include-the-savings-variable/52648?noredirect=1#comment85684_52648).)

The demand function merely describes who is using up how many units of the output.

> The function Y̅=C(Y̅–T̅)+I(r)+G̅ can be altered to: Supply of Y= Demand of Y.

This is not an alteration. The notation in a lot of textbooks is quite poor IMO. $Y=C(Y–T)+I(r)+G$ is the *definition* of the demand function; instead of $Y$ one could write $D_Y$. 
In *equilibrium* Supply of $Y$ = Demand of $Y$. This is not an alteration, but a use of the demand function.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Saving is there *implicitly* through investment, taxes and government spending. You can't include it explicitly in that equation as you would be counting saving twice.

By definition (see Blanchard et al Macroeconomics) *private* saving in macroeconomics is defined as:

$$S=Y-T-C(Y-T) \implies S+T = Y-C(Y-T) \tag{1}$$

Next we can substitute the saving into the AD equation:

$$Y=C(Y–T)+I(r)+G \implies Y- C(Y–T) = I(r) +G\tag{2}$$

The substitution will get us:

$$ S + T = I(r) +G \implies S=I(r) +G-T\tag{3}$$

Now solving equation 3 for investment we get:

$$ I(r)=S + (T-G)$$

which shows that investment will be equal to private saving $S$ and public saving $T-G$. Also I did not written it explicitly but saving is function of interest rate so you could write the last equation also as: $I(r)=S(r) + (T-G)$

Hence saving is already included in the formula $Y=C(Y–T)+I(r)+G $ through investment. As a consequence you cannot explicitly include the saving there again as you would be double counting.

You can either use:

$$Y=C(Y–T)+I(r)+G $$

or in case you wanna include saving explicitly use

$$Y=C(Y–T)+S(r) +T $$

but you cannot do both at the same time as that would be double counting the same variable twice.

Comment: Thank you very much!!